# replace only whole words in LUA string.gsub(), ignore magic characters like colon

Tags: lua

I'm having an issue trying to replace just whole words in a sentence.  I've tried several methods but it just doesn't work properly.  I'm hoping I can get some help here.

So I used the code from the following article:
[Use string.gsub to replace strings, but only whole words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226150/use-string-gsub-to-replace-strings-but-only-whole-words)

```
function replacetext(source, find, replace, wholeword)
  if wholeword then
    find = '%f[%a]'..find..'%f[%A]'
  end
  return (source:gsub(find,replace))
end
```

Here is the demo code I use to test this.

```
local source  = '|Hplayer:YarnBarn-SomeServer:374:WHISPER:YARNBARN-SOMESERVER[113:|cFF342345YarnBarn|r]|h whispers: this is a test YarnBarn YarnBarnME testing for % YarnBarn finally :YarnBarn# YarnBarn'
local find    = 'YarnBarn'
local replace = 'NOODLE'

print(replacetext(source, find, replace, true ))
```

The output I get is the following:

```
|Hplayer:NOODLE-SomeServer:374:WHISPER:YARNBARN-SOMESERVER[113:|cFF342345NOODLE|r]|h whispers: this is a test NOODLE YarnBarnME testing for % NOODLE finally :NOODLE# NOODLE
```

However, the above is incorrect as it's matching words with the colon in the front and it's obviously taking special or magic characters into account.

The correct return should be like this:

```
|Hplayer:YarnBarn-SomeServer:374:WHISPER:YARNBARN-SOMESERVER[113:|cFF342345YarnBarn|r]|h whispers: this is a test NOODLE YarnBarnME testing for % NOODLE finally :YarnBarn# NOODLE
```

I'm trying to get it to replace whole words exactly with nothing in the front or back of the word.  This includes special characters or colon.  That is why on the what should be the correct output, you will notice only the independent words of *YarnBarn* were converted to *NOODLE*.

I don't want to chop up the sentence or just scan a portion of it.  I really need it to parse the entire sentence and replace just the whole words.  I've tried several variations and I just can't seem to get it to work right.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: `find = "%f[^%z%s]"..find.."%f[%z%s]"`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That worked!  Can you explain why it works though?  I'm trying to learn and apparently %z matches a byte 0.  So I'm assuming you are checking for a byte 0 before and after the word?  Not sure how that would even work properly.

Comment: Lua patterns work as if any string was prepended and appended by byte 0.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff AH! That totally makes sense now as to why you are doing checks for %z.  This is good to know for the future thanks!

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff If possible can you post your submission as an Answer below?  That way I can mark it as the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@EgorSkriptunoff posted this solution.

```
function replacetext(source, find, replace, wholeword)
  if wholeword then
    find = "%f[^%z%s]"..find.."%f[%z%s]"
  end
  return (source:gsub(find,replace))
end
```